# textDidEndEditing: - how to filter "Return" key?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

OK, this my situation :

- I'm using an `NSTextField`
- I'm observing the `NSTextDidEndEditingNotification` notification

This is the final method :

```
- (void)handleConsoleInput:(NSNotification*)not
```

This notification is fired whenever (at least from what I've noticed) the user :

- Presses "return"
- Presses "tab"
- Clicks out of the `NSTextField`

However, I'd (obviously) want to limit it to the "return" key.

How am I supposed to do that? I've tested the contents of  the `NSNotification` object sent, and there's no info on the key code or event that triggered the `textDidEndEditing:` notification.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**

**Just noticed :**

- When user clicks out of the `NSTextField`, `[[not userInfo] valueForKey:@"NSTextMovement"]` becomes `0` which means that this case *can* be filtered.
- What about differentiating "tab" and "return", though, which both return `NSTextMovement` values `>0`?

Comment: This is a little convoluted.  Why not just subclass the thing?

Comment: @CodaFi Your answer is correct (for a more *complete* approach, for anyone interested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994663/keydownnsevent-event-is-not-invoked-when-the-focus-is-on-a-text-field ). Please, post your remark as a proper answer and I'll give you all the credit you deserve. Thanks a lot, mate! :-)

Comment: how can we filter space key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly feel that subscribing to the notification is the most efficient way to go about this, more power to you, but I feel it would be miles easier for you to subclass NSTextField and override the relevant event methods.  But, that is of no matter, here's a quick implementation of what I think it should look like:

```
- (void)handleConsoleInput:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSUInteger textMove = [notification.userInfo[@"NSTextMovement"] unsignedIntegerValue];
    if (textMove != NSReturnTextMovement) {
        [self.window makeFirstResponder:notification.object];
    }
}
```

The ending event's type is enumerated in the documentation for [NSText](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSTextDidEndEditingNotification).

Answer (score 2):

The possible values for

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
int movement = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"NSTextMovement"] intValue];
```

of the `NSTextDidEndEditingNotification` are documented as [Movement Codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Movement_Codes) in the "NSText Class Reference":

```
enum {
   NSIllegalTextMovement = 0,
   NSReturnTextMovement  = 0x10,
   NSTabTextMovement     = 0x11,
   NSBacktabTextMovement = 0x12,
   NSLeftTextMovement    = 0x13,
   NSRightTextMovement   = 0x14,
   NSUpTextMovement      = 0x15,
   NSDownTextMovement    = 0x16,
   NSCancelTextMovement  = 0x17,
   NSOtherTextMovement    = 0
};
```

Comment: Wow. That **is** interesting. I don't know... I ended up experimenting with @CodaFi's approach - which *does* work. But your approach definitely solved *my* approach. So +1 for that. (Really informational too!) Thanks mate! :-)